# Install offline SDK in Android Studio and use Eclipse SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have slow connection. I can't download SDK in Android Studio.

Please give me an offline download link of SDK for Android Studio. I already have SDK for Eclipse.

Can I use it in Android Studio?

Comment: You can very well use SDK which you have for Eclipse for AS as well. please set the path correctly. Also ensure you keep it updated as and when you get a better network connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have a installed SDK, you can use it in both Eclipse or Android Studio. To change your SDK location in Android Studio:

1. Android Studio > Preferences
2. Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK
3. Edit to change your SDK path. 
   [image: Here is the screenshot]